# Re-evaluate new objects every time a view/context processor is used in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I need to make queries every time a view or a context processor is used. At the moment I used a queryset. But I realized that I can't use that for my case.

I need to make a query like the queryset to retrieve the latest objects in the database. I need to actually re-evaluate it again so that the users see new objects.

**This is what I use at the moment:**

```
class EntryListView(ListView):

    model = Entry

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EntryListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'all_entries': Entry.objects.filter(status=2, publish_date__lte=datetime.date.today())[:40],
        })
        return context
```

How can I make a query so that it will get the latest 40 objects each time the view or context processor is used?

The result now is that it using a cached version. So it never updates on the site.

**Edit:**

How I access the context in my template is:

```
{% for post in all_entries %}
    {% post.title %}
{% endfor %}
```

**The url:**

```
url(r'^all-entries/$', PostListView.as_view(template_name='all_entries.html'), name='all_entries'),
```

Comment: The queryset in `get_context_data` will be evaluated once for each view and will not be cached. How are you accessing the entries in the template?

Comment: @Alasdair Updated the question now.

Comment: As I said, that queryset will not be cached by Django.

Answer (score 0):

This queryset you are using translates to - Get the first 40 Entry objects whose status is 2 and was published with date <= today. With this logic, the queryset always returns the first 40 entries - this explains why you think the view is caching the results.

```
Entry.objects.filter(status=2, publish_date__lte=datetime.date.today())[:40],
```

We need to order the result in the descending order to get the results in the way you want. I don't know how your model looks but I'm assuming that publish_date is a datefield, so we can't use that. If you have not specified a primary key explicitly, we should be able to use **id** which is created automatically to order our results.

```
Entry.objects.filter(status=2, publish_date__lte=datetime.date.today()).order_by('-id')[:40]
```